# how to fetch 10 minutes before created records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have below format mongodb doc

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5f5b1b5d89967c6c48003346",
    "UID" : "5f5b15ca89967c6c4800327d",
    "_createdAt" : "2020-09-11 12:08:21",
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5f5b16f789967c6c480032d1",
    "UID" : "5f5b15ca89967c6c4800327d",
    "_createdAt" : "2020-09-11 11:49:35",
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "5f5b16b389967c6c480032b8",
    "UID" : "5f5b15ca89967c6c4800327d",
    "_createdAt" : "2020-09-11 11:48:27",
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "5f5b15cd89967c6c48003282",
    "UID" : "5f5b15ca89967c6c4800327d",
    "_createdAt" : "2020-09-11 11:44:37",
}
```

current time is *2020-09-11 12:10:21*

I have to fetch records 10 minutes before _createdAt (current time - 10 minutes).

My expected output

```
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5f5b16f789967c6c480032d1",
    "UID" : "5f5b15ca89967c6c4800327d",
    "_createdAt" : "2020-09-11 11:49:35",
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "5f5b16b389967c6c480032b8",
    "UID" : "5f5b15ca89967c6c4800327d",
    "_createdAt" : "2020-09-11 11:48:27",
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "5f5b15cd89967c6c48003282",
    "UID" : "5f5b15ca89967c6c4800327d",
    "_createdAt" : "2020-09-11 11:44:37",
}
```

Comment: are you using only database or some programming language like php.

Comment: only DB i have filter the records

Comment: which tool are you using Studio3t/ Robo3t or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Consider your collection name is `users` and current time is `2020-09-11 12:10:21`.
So query timestamp would be `2020-09-11 12:00:21`.

```
db.users.find({"_createdAt":{$lt:"2020-09-11 12:00:21"}});

or 

db.getCollection('users').find({"_createdAt":{$lt:"2020-09-11 12:00:21"}});
```