# How to filter 10 minutes ago array in existing multidimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, php-7

I have below array

```
$users = [
[ "_createdAt" = > "2020-09-15 12:10:21", "username" => "A"],
[ "_createdAt" = > "2020-09-15 12:08:24", "username" => "B"]
[ "_createdAt" = > "2020-09-15 11:30:45", "username" => "C"]
[ "_createdAt" = > "2020-09-15 11:08:00", "username" => "D"]
];
```

- Step 1 => i have to find current time - 10 minutes
- Step 2 => i have to keep the usernames($users array) who has created 10
  minutes ago

> For exapmple current time is 2020-09-15 12:15:21

> expected aswer is

```
$users = [
    [ "_createdAt" = > "2020-09-15 11:30:45", "username" => "C"]
    [ "_createdAt" = > "2020-09-15 11:08:00", "username" => "D"]
];
```

Comment: Sounds like a great task. Go ahead!

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Are you trying an alternative approach now, because you ran out of patience waitning for a response to https://stackoverflow.com/q/63895938/1427878 after an hour already?

Comment: @Blackbam & Magnus, sorry, I understood your point now. For future questions will make sure that if guy has attempted and having issue somewhere, will help him/her out.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_filter` and `strtotime`  function for that.

```
$tenMinuteOldTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-10 minutes"));

$newArray = array_filter($users, function($k) use($tenMinuteOldTime ) {
    return $k['_createdAt'] < $tenMinuteOldTime ;
});
```

So if you are in different timezone and you know how forward and backward that timezone is from GMT, you can just modify the `strtotime` parameter.

So for example if we take IST that is GMT+5:30. So that is 330 minutes forward and we want data from 10 mins ago, so we can change parameter to `330 -10 = 320` as follow

```
$tenMinuteOldTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+320 minutes"));
```

Definitely there are other methods to get current time in a given timezone but by seeing the other answer and you're not able to use `new DateTime`, I suggested this quick fix.

Comment: Did you notice that `date` function is returning time in GMT and your time is definitely not in GMT. If so please format date according to your timezone and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter` with `DateTime`.

```php
<?php
   // Users array
   $users = [
        [ "_createdAt" => "2020-09-15 12:10:21", "username" => "A"],
        [ "_createdAt" => "2020-09-15 12:08:24", "username" => "B"],
        [ "_createdAt" => "2020-09-15 11:30:45", "username" => "C"],
        [ "_createdAt" => "2020-09-15 11:08:00", "username" => "D"],
    ];
    
    // get current dateTime
    $currentTime = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    
    // filtering users
    $filteredUsers = array_filter($users, function($user) use ($currentTime) {
            // convert createdAt from string to date
            $createdAt = (new DateTime($user['_createdAt']))->getTimestamp();

            // check the difference is >= 10 minutes (600 seconds)
            return ($currentTime - $createdAt) >= 600;
    });
    
    // display filtered users
    var_export($filteredUsers);
?>
```

Comment: Is there any alternate way, because i am not able to use this *new DateTime("2020-09-15 12:20:00")*

Comment: @NallammalT - _"I am not able to use this new DateTime("2020-09-15 12:20:00")"_ - Why not? 
What happens? If you're under a namespace, you need to use `new \DateTime(...)` or add `use DateTime;` in the top (right after the namespace). If that's not the issue, you should explain what actually happens so we can help you sort it out since this should def. work.