# Filter array rows if datetime value is within 10 minutes of target time

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, foreach, date-difference

I do a foreach on an object that I call `$file`. This object has a property which is the datetime ($file[6]) and another with the name ($file[0]). I need to add the object to an array if the difference between `createDate` and `$file[6]` are within 10 minutes of each other.

My desired result structure is:

```
[
  [ $file[0], $file[6] ], // More than 1 results
  [ $file[0], $file[6] ],
  ...
]
```

As you can see in the code below:

```
$createDate = $prop['created_date'];
$result = array();
    
foreach($obj['files'] as $file) {
     
    $fileName = $file[0];
    $fileDateTime = $file[6];

    $differenceInSeconds = strtotime($fileDateTime) - strtotime($createDate);
    $differenceInSeconds = abs($differenceInSeconds);

    $convertMinutes = 10 * 60; // 10 minutes
    
    if ($differenceInSeconds < $convertMinutes) {
        // Need a array of array that show the name ($file[0]) and datetime ($file[6])
        // when the difference between $createDate and $file[6] is less 10 minutes  
        // (or is between 0 and 600, I guess)
        array_push($result, $file); // Here need push array name and date
        break;
    }
      
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Var_dump in $createDate and $file show this:

$createDate:

```
DataType: json Message: object(IP_DateTime)#77 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2022-04-25 03:38:15.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(17) "America/Sao_Paulo"
}
```

$file:

```
array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "20220407_10_22_30_L100.SVL"
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    string(8) "20220407"
    [3]=>
    int(4766)
    [4]=>
    int(307)
    [5]=>
    int(101366)
    [6]=>
    string(19) "2022-04-07 13:34:10"
    [7]=>
    int(0)
    [8]=>
    int(1)
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it is poorly explained. You should use https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ so you can write in your own language

Comment: Ok I just did..

Comment: @Elton So is it true that all of your coding attempt works perfectly except you didn't know how to push a 2-element array into the result array?

Comment: @mickmackusa The if part is still not working 100% and I really didn't know how to do this array structure inside an array with 2 values

Comment: How is the if condition not working as desired?  (For the record, I am deciding if this question should be answered or closed.  I have a [solution](https://3v4l.org/7Qan0). I am not here for points; I am here to make sure SO content is clear, complete, on-topic, and unique. Notice that I had to create my own test data because this question does not have a reasonably sized [mcve].)

Comment: Related: [How to filter 10 minutes ago array in existing multidimensional array using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63896529/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if I understood correctly

```
$createDate = $prop['created_date'];
$result = array();
$index = 0;

foreach ($obj['files'] as $file) {
    $fileName = $file[0];
    $fileDateTime = $file[6];

    $differenceInSeconds = strtotime($fileDateTime) - strtotime($createDate);
    $differenceInSeconds = abs($differenceInSeconds);

    $convertMinutes = 600; // 10 minutes

    if ($differenceInSeconds < $convertMinutes) {
        $result[$index] = array($fileName,$fileDateTime);
        $index++;
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Adding a bit of explanation: I'm using $result[$index] instead of array_push because if you push an array into an array, it would just push in all its items instead of adding the new array as an actual array, which was happening to you.

Comment: Maybe because it worked? I don't have the most expertise nor I've been around much on Stackoverflow so if instead of being so rude, why don't you make a constructive comment instead and teach me/us how to improve my answer by making another so it'd be actually helpful for the person who asked the question, for me and other people who read this since saying that it isn't helpful and not explaining why or giving an alternative doesn't really add to the discussion

Comment: @mickmackusa please, make a better solution, because this one, even though you say it wasn't explained well, it worked perfectly!

Comment: I did not downvote. And I offered two bits of actionable criticism.  Maybe the tone was too grumpy, but you've been here for 7 years.  Here it is again as if I was a robot...   "This answer is missing its educational explanation." And "`$index` is an unnecessary variable declaration."  The reason for my distaste of code-only answers which collect uv's comes from the fact that new contributors continue to post code-only answers as long as they get upvotes.  If they were not upvoted, then maybe contributors would put more effort in crafting a better answer. See [answer].

Comment: @mickmackusa Okay then, but how would you go about coming up with a solution. I would like to understand. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Just added a bit of explanation, it's true I could have explained more. Even though I've had this account for 7 years, I'm just starting to get involved other than searching for answers I need. I'll try to better explain my answers from now on, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This task can be directly and efficiently completed by preparing string-comparable datetime values before looping.  Because the datetime format is "big-endian", you don't need to perform iterated math/date calculations. You can use simple, clear greater/less than operators to determine qualifying data sets.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7Qan0))

```
$prop['created_date'] = '2022-04-07 13:38:15.000000';

$obj['files'] = [
    ["20220407_10_22_30_L100.SVL", 2, "20220407", 4766, 307, 101366, "2022-04-07 13:24:10"],
    ["20220407_10_22_30_L101.SVL", 3, "20220407", 4767, 308, 101367, "2022-04-07 13:29:10"],
    ["20220407_10_22_30_L102.SVL", 4, "20220407", 4768, 309, 101368, "2022-04-07 13:34:10"],
    ["20220407_10_22_30_L103.SVL", 5, "20220407", 4769, 310, 101369, "2022-04-07 13:39:10"],
    ["20220407_10_22_30_L104.SVL", 6, "20220407", 4770, 311, 101370, "2022-04-07 13:44:10"],
    ["20220407_10_22_30_L105.SVL", 7, "20220407", 4771, 312, 101371, "2022-04-07 13:49:10"],
];

// prepare the date range data only once, before looping
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($prop['created_date'] . ' - 10 minutes'));
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($prop['created_date'] . ' + 10 minutes'));

$result =[];
foreach ($obj['files'] as $file) {
    if ($from <= $file[6] && $file[6] <= $to) {
        $result[] = [$file[0], $file[6]];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '20220407_10_22_30_L101.SVL',
    1 => '2022-04-07 13:29:10',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '20220407_10_22_30_L102.SVL',
    1 => '2022-04-07 13:34:10',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '20220407_10_22_30_L103.SVL',
    1 => '2022-04-07 13:39:10',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '20220407_10_22_30_L104.SVL',
    1 => '2022-04-07 13:44:10',
  ),
)
```